# Are there alternative techniques to closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

In the code below, I used closure to "save" the "this" reference and pass it to a callback. But i was wondering, are there alternative techniques to accomplish the same thing?

```
function App()
{   
    this.number = 75;
}

App.prototype.xmlHandler = function(self)
{
    if (this.number == 99) //true at run-time
        console.log("this.number == 99 is true");
    else
        console.log("this.number == 99 is false");

    if (self.number == app.number) //true at run-time
        console.log("self.number == app.number is true");
    else
        console.log("self.number == app.number is false");
};

App.prototype.loadXML = function(url, handler)
{
    var self = this;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.number = 99;
    req.addEventListener("load", function(){handler.call(req, self);}, false);
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.send();
};

App.prototype.init = function()
{
    this.loadXML('resources.xml', this.xmlHandler);
};

var app = new App();
app.init();
```

Under the xmlHandler method, there are essentially two different "this" (one [this] for the req object and the other [self] for the app object). so, are there alternative techniques to get two different "this" values under one roof?

Comment: Shouldn't `var self = this` just do the trick of, saving the current context, fine,
Why would you need an other way of doing this?

Comment: You can save the reference as a property in another object accessible in that context, e.g. in this case the `event.target`. But again, why the solution above is not good?

Comment: I'm curious if there exist alternative techniques to closures. Or, are closure the only thing available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are utility functions that can create a closure, but without the verbosity.

In this particular case you can use the ES5 [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method (shims are readily available for older browsers):

```
App.prototype.loadXML = function(url, handler) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.number = 99;
    req.addEventListener("load", handler.bind(this, req), false);
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.send();
};
```

The result will be that `handler` (which is equal to `this.xmlHandler`) will be called with `this` still equal to its original value (i.e. the `App` object) and with `req` as the first parameter.

Strictly speaking this is the opposite way around to your current definition of `xmlHandler`, but it's more logical IMHO to have `this` refer to the `App` object instead of it being passed as a parameter.  That function would then be written:

```
App.prototype.xmlHandler = function(req, evt) {
    if (req.number == ...) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Note how the `evt` parameter is also available - the parameter(s) passed in `.bind` are *prepended* to any parameters that are supplied by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are no alternatives to closures.

For the `this` binding, you can use the [`.bind()` Function method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (native with ES5.1, easily shimable) if you need only one of them. For "two different 'this' values" you could need to write a similiar function that passes the second context as a parameter, but the closure is simpler then imho.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, the only way you can get this to work is by using closures.

That said, looking at your code, I don't think `.loadXML()` should really care about context at all:

```
App.prototype.loadXML = function(url, handler)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.number = 99;
    req.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.send();
};
```

This cleans up the function, so that what you really want to do can be expressed inside the `.init()`:

```
App.prototype.init = function()
{
    var self = this;

    this.loadXML('resources.xml', function(evt) {
        // this refers to the XMLHttpRequest
        // self refers to the current App instance
        self.xmlHandler(this);
    });
};
```

Comment: or even `this.loadXML(..., this.xmlHandler.bind(this));`

Comment: @Alnitak Oh, that's nifty :)

Comment: @Alnitak But the problem is that you would lose the `XMLHttpRequest` reference in the process :)

Comment: ah - you mean within `.loadXML`? - hat's a problem because the `XMLHttpRequest` is _lexically_ scoped so the only way to pass it to the handler is as `this` or through a closure.  The `.bind` call emulates the second block of code, but doesn't resolve the problem your first code block has in passing `req` to `handler`.

Comment: ah - what you would do change `.loadXML` to say `req.addEventListener("load", handler.bind(this, req), false)`.  It's still creating a closure, but it's less verbose.  You would then pass `this.xmlHandler` directly in the `this.loadXML` call.

Comment: I saw your edit to my answer but it overlapped with one of mine so I reverted it (and then made the same edit).  Hopefully that all makes sense... :)

Comment: @Alnitak Yep, it was a minor change anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you're looking for. In any case this is sharing 'this'.
The object 'inner' isn't retaining its objectness because it's become a method of 'outer', but it's sharing.

Let me know if you are looking for something more specific than what I've written here.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="result1"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
</body>
<script>

var outer = function(val, obj){

    this['inner'] = obj['inner'];
            this.val = val;
    this.inner('result1')
    this.val2 = 'not 2';
    this.inner('result2');
};
var inner = function(id){
    this.val2 = this.val2 || 2;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'this.val='+this.val+'this.val2='+this.val2;

};

new outer('thing', {'inner': inner});
</script>
</html>
```